# Wi-Fi suddenly disappeared

Tags: networking

I've been using eOS for few years now on the same machine and all works fine. However today, for no apparent reason, there is no wi-fi network support. The Network Manager doesn't even suggest wi-fi or scan for wi-fi networks. I am lucky enough to have a USB wireless adapter and after plugging it in, I get wi-fi access again.

What could have happened? How can I troubleshoot? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Would you check with a live sesión (USB or Dvd) to determine if  it's not due to a hardware problem?

Comment: There might have been a kernel upgrade recently, you might want to try to reboot and select an older kernel at the grub prompt.

Answer (score -1):

I never had problems before but, in the last 6-7 days, the same problem appeared to me, too, once or two a day.
A reboot resolved the problem but sometimes, suddntly, the wi-fi totally desapperas, again. I'm using an HP latop.

Here's the last lines from from dmesg, after the problem just appeared (in this case opening Firefox with saved tabs just after login, but the problem usually happens after some hours of work):

```
[   47.188483] Code: 54 09 00 4d 85 e4 74 1e 49 8b 04 24 49 8b 7c 24 08 49 83 c4 18 48 89 de e8 e1 07 7c c4 49 8b 04 24 48 85 c0 75 e6 e9 51 ff ff ff <0f> 0b 5b 41 5c 5d c3 66 90 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 
[   47.188516] ---[ end trace 89da9a8786820492 ]---
[   47.285821] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   47.285842] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
[   47.303971] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 98:54:1b:a3:3e:ff
[   47.516290] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[   47.516432] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   47.516435] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000100, count: 6
[   47.516438] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.1044073957.0
[   47.516440] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000034 | NMI_INTERRUPT_WDG           
[   47.516443] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[   47.516445] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   47.516447] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00041702 | branchlink2
[   47.516449] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00044696 | interruptlink1
[   47.516452] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000C64A | interruptlink2
[   47.516454] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   47.516456] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000002 | data2
[   47.516459] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x07030000 | data3
[   47.516461] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   47.516463] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00035095 | tsf low
[   47.516466] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   47.516468] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   47.516470] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00035095 | time gp2
[   47.516472] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000009 | uCode revision type
[   47.516475] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000001D | uCode version major
[   47.516477] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x3E3B4DE5 | uCode version minor
[   47.516479] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000210 | hw version
[   47.516482] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00C89200 | board version
[   47.516484] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0012016A | hcmd
[   47.516486] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x02023080 | isr0
[   47.516489] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   47.516491] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000002 | isr2
[   47.516493] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x004000C0 | isr3
[   47.516495] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | isr4
[   47.516497] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0012016A | last cmd Id
[   47.516500] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   47.516502] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
[   47.516504] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   47.516506] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   47.516509] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   47.516511] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000007 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   47.516514] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x14031202 | timestamp
[   47.516516] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00341020 | flow_handler
[   47.516527] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT calibrations: -5
[   47.528118] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

Comment: Please user **answer** to post solution of the problem shared. In the meantime read this, [How do I write a good answer?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)